# Uploading rpm to Redhat satellite from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

My task is to build my project , create rpm and then upload the rpm to Redhat satellite.
I am using jenkins to build project and create rpm but the last task has become headcache. I am facing following issues.

1. Jenkins user doesn't have permission to upload rpm to satellite.
2. su also doesn't work with jenkins as it doesn't have terminal.

Now i am begining to feel that i might not be able to achieve this with jenkins. [Although i am very keen to do it via jenkins]
Can somebody suggest some way out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a user in Satellite for jenkins. This user needs management rights to the channel you want to upload RPMs.

Then you need to create jobs in jenkins which uses https://fedorahosted.org/spacewalk/wiki/spacecmd to push the RPM to the Satellite server.